# To access to/ To access it / to access?

Tags: grammar

I want to describe to someone in my code, that I am writing it in a certain place for him,so he can have an easier access to it.

So I wrote : 
**' So it will be easier to access it '** 
But I am not sure about the syntax.
Is it : 
**' So it will be easier to access to' ?**

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
the definition/explanation and examples in a dictionary or other trusted reference. For example [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Answer (score 1):

> So it will be easier to access it

This is OK.

> So it will be easier to access to

This isn't grammatically correct; the closest correct version I can think of would be *So it will be easier to gain access to*.

However, I would probably choose neither, and instead simply say:

> So it will be easier to access.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :-)

Comment: @AntoineBeine if this answered your question, can you click on the little check-mark on the left side to mark it as an accepted answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that "So it will be easier to gain access to" is actually not grammatically correct either.  You would need an "it" after "to":  "So it will be easier to gain access to it".  I agree that "easier to access" is the simplest and most natural, though.